# Xcode ERROR ITMS-90022: Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain app icon 120x120, 167x167, 152x152

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I've been searching for a solution to this Xcode issue for hours! I realize there are a bunch of posts on stack overflow with the same issue, but most of them are outdated (Xcode 9 or earlier and from 2016/2017). Does anyone have a solution to this issue? I am running Xcode 11.4.1 and all of the AppIcon images are correctly set in the Assets.xcassets folder. The application runs fine when building to simulator/iPhone and it was uploading to AppStoreConnect with the same settings last version of my app (a few weeks ago).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Don't include special characters in your app's Display Name. I'm not sure how they're connected, but the Display Name on my application had ~ in the title and after changing from ~title~ to title the build uploaded and this error message went away. Hope this helps someone ~lol~

Comment: Is there a reason to think that problem affects this specific question?

Comment: This is the error message I was receiving and this was the solution...

Comment: I had a early-phase project, we had left double quote characters in the name (because it was a placeholder app name). We couldn't get it into TestFlight without a name change, but we didn't see this problem/error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is confusing because the 120x120 reference doesn't clearly state that you need to fix the "60pt" app icon asset in a 2x format.

The iPad version of the error can be solved by turning off iPad as a platform choice. I think it might be good to do that as you troubleshoot.

Comment: Just noticed that when iPhone-only apps are downloaded on iPad, they will appear in iPad OS springboard without an icon... so my answer is probably a workaround, even though App store does not require iPad-sized icons, you should provide them.